# Match parts of a string

Tags: regex, string, vb.net

I have 2 strings that each contain 25 characters. E.g.

```
   X = "0000111111110111111111110"
   Y = "0000011111000000000000000"
```

What would be the most efficient method to identify, true or false if every position that has a "1" string Y also has a "1" in string X? In this example it should return True as there are 1s in X that match the positions of all 1s in Y.

I could read each character position and do a comparison for all 25 but was hoping some clever person would know of a more elegant way.

Comment: Are the strings always 25 characters long? If not, what is the maximum length?

Comment: yes always 25 in length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *easier* way is to use [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_) to parse the string as a binary literal and perform binary `AND`:

```
Public Function MatchAsBinary(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Boolean
    Dim x_int = Convert.ToInt32(x, 2)
    Dim y_int = Convert.ToInt32(y, 2)

    Return (x_int And y_int) = y_int
End Function
```

The *faster* (~10 times in release build) way is to compare the chars directly:

```
Public Function MatchAsChars(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To y.Length - 1
        If y(i) = "1"c AndAlso x(i) = "0"c Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you regard the strings as binary numbers, you can convert them to numbers and then use the bitwise and operator, like this:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim X = "0000111111110111111111110"
        Dim Y = "0000011111000000000000000"
        Dim Xb = Convert.ToInt64(X, 2)
        Dim Yb = Convert.ToInt64(Y, 2)

        Console.WriteLine((Xb And Yb) = Yb)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

That will output `True` and work for strings of up to 64 characters.

Or, following on from your comment, you could use `Convert.ToInt32` as that would give enough bits for your data.

Comment: Thanks however i'm getting false when it should be true?

Comment: y      "1111100010100111000111001" String
      x     "1111100000000000000000000" String
  Xint 32505856 Integer
  Yint 32591417 Integer
  ((Xint And Yint) = Yint) False Boolean

Comment: @Mark It will be `true` if you swap `y` and `x`. You've specified that it's `y` that decides which bits are important.

Answer (score 1):

Can do something similar @JoshD said above, but use `Convert.ToInt32(Y, 2)` to convert from a binary string to an integer.

```
Xint = Convert.ToInt32(X, 2)
Yint = Convert.ToInt32(Y, 2)

return ((Xint And Yint) = Yint)
```

Answer (score 1):

This includes what others have shown plus a test for each bit one at a time.

```
    Dim s As String = "0000011111000000000000000"
    Dim X As String = "0000111111110111111111110"
    Dim Y As String = "0000011111000000000000000"

    Dim xi As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(X, 2)
    Dim yi As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Y, 2)


    'check each bit
    For i As Integer = 0 To 24
        Dim msk As Integer = 1 << i
        If (msk And xi) = msk AndAlso (msk And yi) = msk Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Bit {0} on in both", i)
        End If
    Next

    'all bits
    Dim rslt As Integer = xi And yi
    s = Convert.ToString(rslt, 2).PadLeft(25, "0"c)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim intY As Integer = CInt(Y)    
Dim res As Boolean = (CInt(X) And intY) = intY
```

Convert them to integers, get all instances of matching 1's with a bitwise And, then compare to see if Y was changed by that comparison. If the comparison preserved the original Y, the result will be True.

Comment: You will want to use `Convert.ToInt32(Y, 2)` to convert the binary string to an integer